# crystal report view

Tags: crystal-reports

suppose if i have a few hundred thousand records in dataset how can i show this in Crystal report by allow multiple page...

can u provide some valuable solution?

Comment: Thats too wide a question. I would like to know, why you should let the large number of records be shown to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Creating Crystal Reports using C#
  with Datasets](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreatingCrystalReports.aspx)
- [Generate ASP.NET Crystal Report
  using DataSet](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rsubhajit/CrystalReportwithDataSet03012006060655AM/CrystalReportwithDataSet.aspx)
- [C# Crystal Reports without database](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-without-database.htm)